# How can I get blog to work in TabBarView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get my blog which uses REST API from a Wordpress site to show in `TabBarView`
And I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. First I tried `Widget blogSection = WordpressBlog(posts: posts);`but I was getting error:'only static members can be accessed in initializers' ... so I placed my code in `void initState(){...}` There are 3 tabs: infoSection, blogSection and contactSection. Two of the tabs are hard coded and work ok. Also I've extracted my blog to `wordpress_blog.dart` and named it:`WordpressBlog`This works well on my other blog page.  Here's the full code:

```
import 'package:cmfiflutterapp/components/wordpress_blog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: GlobalCompassion()));
}

class GlobalCompassion extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => GlobalCompassionState();
}

class GlobalCompassionState extends State {
  // Base URL for our wordpress API
  final String apiUrl = "https://cmf.international/wp-json/wp/v2/";

  // Empty list for our posts
  List posts;

  // Function to fetch list of posts
  Future<String> getPosts() async {
    var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(apiUrl + "posts?_embed"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    // fill our posts list with results and update state
    setState(() {
      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      posts = resBody;
    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState( );
    this.getPosts( );
    blogSection = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        WordpressBlog(posts: posts)
      ],
      );
  }

  Widget infoSection = SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          ...
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Image.asset('assets/images/glocompassion.png'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Text(
          ...
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

  Widget blogSection;

  Widget contactSection = SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
          ...
    ),
  );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: 200,
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: Text('GlobalCompassion'),
                    background: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/gcompassion.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  sliver: SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                      TabBar(
                          labelColor: Colors.blue,
                          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: 'About Us'),
                            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.create), text: 'Blog'),
                            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.contact_mail), text: 'Contact')
                          ])
                    ]),
                  ),
                )
              ];
            },
            body: Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: TabBarView(
                children: <Widget>[infoSection, blogSection, contactSection],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated ... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally  solved this. 3 things I had to change.

First was to make my `List` static ... so changed this:`List posts;` to this:`static List posts;`

Second was to remove unneccesary code from `initState` so from this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState( );
    this.getPosts( );
    blogSection = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        WordpressBlog(posts: posts)
      ],
      );
  }
```

to this:

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState( );
        this.getPosts( );
      }
```

Thirdly was to add a `Scaffold` to the `blogSection` like this:

```
 Widget blogSection = Scaffold(
       body: WordpressBlog(posts: posts)
    )
```

That did it. Now I having a working Wordpress REST API blog in flutter tabs. Thank you all!